# How to redirect a few urls in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have some requests from users to make some pages indiscoverable in search engines. While it would be an idea to use `robots.txt`, I would like to redirect such pages to a page explaining what happened in this case, using NGINX.

In essence, this is what I want:

```
http://example.com/some/url.pdf --> http://example.com/redirected_due_to_privacy
http://example.com/another_url --> http://example.com/redirected_due_to_privacy
http://example.com/and/another --> http://example.com/redirected_due_to_privacy
```

I want all the other URLs to point itself (remain the same).
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the business logic behind that, how do you distinct which request either to serve or redirect? Should user come from same domain? If so, this is the answer: http://serverfault.com/a/710171/61607

Comment: @Anatoly Apologies if my explanation wasn't clear, but that's not the case. I'm not trying to distinct between referrers. Some pages in my Website have sensitive information regarding public figures, and sometimes the public figures themselves don't want their info to be discovered by search engines. So we're trying to redirect those pages to a page that explains the reason for redirects to the users.

Comment: Do you mean those pages must be accessible for only authenticated users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[map](http://ngx.cc/r/map), rather than [rewrite](http://ngx.cc/r/rewrite), [return](http://ngx.cc/r/return) or redirect, is useful in this case:

```
map $uri $privacyredir {
  default 0;
  /some/url.pdf 1;
  /another_url 1;
  /and/another 1;
}

...

server {
  ...
  # putting this inside a location is be more efficient
  if ($privacyredir) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/redirected_due_to_privacy;
  }
}
```

([Solution suggested by @vandemar](http://p.ngx.cc/3f))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create different urls for each pages, and add the rewrite rules in location module of nginx.conf.

Such as:

rewrite "^/redirected_due_to_privacy$"    /some/url.pdf break;

rewrite "^/redirected_due_to_privacy1$"   /another_url;

rewrite "^/redirected_due_to_privacy2$"   /and/another

Comment: Do I need to increment the number behind `^/redirected_due_to_privacy`? It seems difficult to maintain, as the list of pages that need to be redirected may sometimes change with deletions and additions (which will probably create human generated errors). If the increment is mandatory, is there a way I can use a script to ensure that the increments are created automatically?

Comment: Yeah, I means you cannot use a constant url mapping to some different urls. So we cannot write a rule to rewrite the same url to different urls. The number behind ^/redirected_due_to_privacy can be created automatically, all of these depends you! Of course, you can use script to make changes with deletions and additions!

Comment: Another idea is  rewrite "^/redirected_due_to_privacy$" to a constant url. we can use a router and params to dispach the  detailed requests.